# SQlite primary key: datatype mismatch

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have [read a bit](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1) about `sqlite` because I need the ability of an `autoincrement primary key` column in my table.

They give the information:

> If you declare a column of a table to be INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, then
>   whenever you insert a NULL into that column of the table, the NULL is
>   automatically converted into an integer which is one greater than the
>   largest value of that column over all other rows in the table, or 1 if
>   the table is empty.

I have tried to insert `NULL` into the primary key column and got the following issue:

```
[INSERT INTO maschinen(name,id_maschine,description,id_maschine_local_row) VALUES (?,?,?,?)] datatype mismatch
E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=FLATTENER No. 1 id_maschine=6 description=Flattener the BIG one id_maschine_local_row=NULL
```

my create statement:

```
CREATE TABLE maschinen(id_maschine_local_row INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, id_maschine INTEGER, name STRING, description STRING)
```

What am I doing wrong?

If I insert a row without without putting some data to the insert statement vor id_maschine_local_row it is always 0.

DatabaseHandler:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Machines
    private static final String TABLE_MASCHINEN = "maschinen";

    private static final String KEY_MASCHINE_LOCAL_ROW_ID = "id_maschine_local_row";
    private static final String KEY_MASCHINE_ID = "id_maschine";
    private static final String KEY_MASCHINE_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_MASCHINE_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    private String CREATE_MASCHINEN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MASCHINEN + "(" + KEY_MASCHINE_LOCAL_ROW_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_MASCHINE_ID + " INTEGER, "+ KEY_MASCHINE_NAME + " STRING, " + KEY_MASCHINE_DESCRIPTION + " STRING)" ;

    (...)
     public long addMaschine(Maschine mMaschine) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // machine data
        ContentValues valuesMachine = new ContentValues();
        valuesMachine.put(KEY_MASCHINE_LOCAL_ROW_ID, "NULL"); /* Without that line for each machine the local row id is 0. With that line as suggested in the article I get the issue */
        valuesMachine.put(KEY_MASCHINE_ID, mMaschine.getId());
        valuesMachine.put(KEY_MASCHINE_NAME, mMaschine.getName());
        valuesMachine.put(KEY_MASCHINE_DESCRIPTION, mMaschine.getDescription());

        //characteristics data
        List<Characteristic> characteristicList = new ArrayList<Characteristic>();
        characteristicList.addAll(mMaschine.getCharacteristics());

        for(int i = 0; i < mMaschine.getCharacteristics().size(); i++){
            ContentValues valuesCharacteristics = new ContentValues();

            //valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_LOCAL_ROW_ID, "NULL");
            valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_ID, characteristicList.get(i).getCharacteristic_id());
            valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_ID_MASCHINE, characteristicList.get(i).getId_maschine());
            valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_NAME, characteristicList.get(i).getName());
            valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_DESCRIPTION, characteristicList.get(i).getDescription());
            valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_TYPE, characteristicList.get(i).getType());
            valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_VALUE, characteristicList.get(i).getValue());
            valuesCharacteristics.put(KEY_CHARACTERISTIC_IS_CHANGED, characteristicList.get(i).getIsChanged());

            db.insert(TABLE_CHARACTERISTICS, null, valuesCharacteristics);
        }

        long machine_id = db.insert(TABLE_MASCHINEN, null, valuesMachine);

        db.close();

        return machine_id;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Inserting `null` just like that produces:

[image]

Comment: Did you try to remove the 'AUTOINCREMENT' ?

Comment: @user3793589 yes, I did, I get the same error for that

Comment: Can you post your insert query code?

Comment: please correct me, if I am wrong, but you can find it in the error printing that you can find in the post

Comment: Can you post the actual code (or method) where you re calling all this for the insertion ?

Comment: I meant exactly what @user3793589 told. Post your java code.

Comment: what if you remove the ' " '?

Comment: like --> valuesMachine.put(KEY_MASCHINE_LOCAL_ROW_ID, null);

Comment: I get then: Ambiguous method call Both put(String, String) in ContentValues and put(String, Values) match. The message seems like everything is okay but I cannot compile that code and it is marked red. @user3793589 I have updated my post to make it more clearly

Comment: Let's try this :

remove --> valuesMachine.put(KEY_MASCHINE_LOCAL_ROW_ID, "NULL");

and replace : long machine_id = db.insert(TABLE_MASCHINEN, null, valuesMachine);

by long machine_id = db.insert(TABLE_MASCHINEN, KEY_MASCHINE_LOCAL_ROW_ID, valuesMachine);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AUTOINCREMENT filed not insert value  system auto input

```
INSERT INTO maschinen(name,id_maschine,description,id_maschine_local_row) VALUES (?,?,?,?)
```

->
    INSERT INTO maschinen(name,id_maschine,description) VALUES (?,?,?)

-> input seq  create table filed seq equals

```
INSERT INTO maschinen(id_maschine,name,description) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Comment: But then the field id_machine_local_row keeps being 0 for ever row

Comment: input seq create table filed seq equals

INSERT INTO maschinen(id_maschine,name,description) VALUES (?,?,?)

Comment: @jublikon, based on the answer you gave here, something might be wrong with your table because normally, if 'id_maschine_local_row ' is a primary key column it cannot have several '0' values. I will suggest you to uninstall the app and install it again

Comment: @user3793589 I agree that this is a very good hint that is often forgotten. This time I have uninstalled the app every time I did something on the database code.